# CCJSqlParserManager.parse does not support NOW()?

Tags: java, sql

I used this code in my program:

```
CCJSqlParserManager pm = new CCJSqlParserManager();
net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.Statement statement = 
                                     pm.parse(new StringReader(processedSql));
```

the processdSql is 
`INSERT INTO　XX(FOO, BAR, CREATE_TIME) VALUES(foo, bar, NOW())`
but after `pm.parse()`, the `NOW()` in the sql changed to `NOW`, the bracket was missing!

Comment: Can you try to replace `NOW` by `NOW()` after `pm.parse()` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I think this work around makes sense. But is there any better idea?

Comment: Maybe you'd need to adapt the grammar the parser is able to read and rebuild all the CCJSqlParserManager project ;)